# Laravel object of model is null

Tags: php, laravel

i have a model in `app/models/Emails.php`:

```
<?php

class Emails extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'emails';
}
```

Next i create a object in my controller:

```
$emails = new Emails;
var_dump($emails);
```

And i get:

```
object(Emails)#125 (1) {
  ["connection":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

My connection to database is ok  and in local config and prodaction config

Comment: What do you want? This is the expected behavior (a connection will only be established/set in the model the first time you run a query)

Comment: I want save to database. I try this: `$emails = new Emails; $emails->name = 'test'; $emails->save();` and get error `Call to undefined method Emails::save()`

Comment: This looks a lot like your class isn't extending `Eloquent` correctly. Try this in your `Emails` class: `class Emails extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

Comment: This seems very strange to me. Can you please make sure that you're using the right file / class?

Comment: yes, i sure.  if i used wrong class, then i getting  Class `'Emails' not found `

Comment: Okay. Maybe try running `composer dump-autoload` that helps sometimes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67799/discussion-between-ivaaaan-and-lukasgeiter).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. I renamed the `Emails.php` and class name to `Email` and it work for me

Comment: Very weird. I had a similar problem, renaming the model to remove the cammelCase worked.